# How can I access an SVG included as part of my new Plasmoid in Plasma 5?

Tags: svg, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm trying to learn how to create Plasmoids. Right now, I have a custom SVG file that I would like to include with the Plasmoid. I can't seem to access SVG files that aren't part of my current theme, thus if I installed the plasmoid on a different installation, I would also have to add the SVG to whatever theme the user is using.

Is there a way to include the SVG in the plasmoid package, and have it installed when the plasmoid is installed? Or, otherwise, is there a way to access an SVG file that is located in the plasmoid's directory, rather than the Theme's directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path of the icon, so let's say you have a directory structure like this:

```
plasmoid/contents
plasmoid/contents/metadata.desktop
plasmoid/contents/ui
plasmoid/contents/ui/main.qml
```

And you want to use the icon in your main.qml, you can add a folder like images or whatever you want to call it and put your image into that folder:

```
plasmoid/contents/images/your_icon.png
```

now in your main.qml you can reference that icon by using smth like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image{
    source: "../images/your_icon.png"
}
```